# Couldn't read a mailbox folder which has '/' in it. I'm using IMAP protocol to read a mail box

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

Hi I'm connecting to a mailbox using IMAP protocol and list the folders and processes mails in that folder using java mail. Whenever a mailbox folder has '/' in it I don't get any error or Exception in code instead i'm getting an error email says "The name of one or more of your folders includes the character "/" or more than 250 characters. Folders with names that include this character can't be downloaded to your IMAP e-mail program. Please rename these folders:
•Test / Test (Test / Test)"

Now how can i change folder name from my java code itself?

Here is the code i have used in java.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
      props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
      props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
      props.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");
      props.setProperty("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
      props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
      props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
      props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");
      props.put("mail.debug", "true");

      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
      store = session.getStore("imaps");
      store.connect("**********",993,"User**","Pass****");

      Folder defaultFolder = store.getDefaultFolder();
      System.out.println(defaultFolder.getFullName());

      if (defaultFolder.list().length != 0) {
          System.out.println(ListFolders(defaultFolder.list()));
      }
```

Comment: is there any script which can rename the folder which has '/' in it?.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an email, this problem is very likely a limitation of your server software, and you're not going to work around it in code.  It looks like you'll have to rename it in your web console, and avoid making folders with this character in it in the future.

The email seems pretty clear that the server is not going to export it to your client, so there's nothing you can change there.

What is your server software?

Comment: We are using Microsoft Exchange Server.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're seeing the result of IMAP naming support (and many other naming standards). MAPI is more generous and lets you use some special characters including forward slash when naming folders.

Javamail has no support for MAPI and has no intention to in the future. If you'd like to test the theory, you could try using a java MAPI library such as [jmapi](https://github.com/briandealwis/jmapi) to read the folders. Then you shouldn't need to rename the folders.

Comment: is that jmapi available in maven repository?

Comment: It was created some time ago and seems inactive. Unfortunately it's not in a maven or nexus repo.